# How to bundle puppeteer for production deployment using webpack?

Tags: typescript, express, webpack, node-modules, puppeteer

I'm creating a node API with express which would create a PDF using puppeteer for a given url. How can I bundle my application for production with webpack? I don't want to globally install puppeteer and express in the server where I will be hosting it and I don't want to call `npm install` on the server. I want puppeteer and express to come together with the js files. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone curious how I solved this - I used webpack with following config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/server.ts",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
      },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    externals: nodeExternals()
}

export default config;
```

And in Continuous Integration server I run following commands:

```
npm install
webpack
npm ci
```

The trick here is `npm ci` (since npm v6) which removes devDependencies from `node_modules`. After that I include `node_modules` to deployment package together with transpiled `js` files

Comment: you mean you checked in the node_modules folder with the code?

Comment: No, I didn't. I think on the CI server `npm install` installs all the dependencies including dev dependencies like puppeteer, then webpack bundles all that into executable js. `npm ci` then removes `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I use puppeteer in the dependencies not the dev dependencies, and I had to add node_modules to my repo, I couldn't gert it bundled in the .js output

Comment: I have an issue like yours but haven't gotten lucky fixing it yet

Comment: do you mind sharing the package.json file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't work on the project anymore, I don't have it.