# Puppeteer in chrome extension, without puppeteer-web

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

Is it possible to create a chrome extension , containing a puppeteer script to scrape and do some browser automation.

I would like to create one where a user would enter a url click a button then a puppeteer script runs, is this possible if so what would be the best way to implement?

Seen some answers referring to puppeteer-web, but seems the Puppeteer team removed puppeteer-web, is there a new way of implementing this?

Comment: No. You will have to rewrite the script.

Comment: Ok rewrite in what way?, is there another library which may work such as playwright

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use puppeteer inside chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184255/can-i-use-puppeteer-inside-chrome-extension)

Comment: No that answer uses puppeteer-web, i believe this has been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, it is not possible.

Puppeteer runs only on Node.Js at the moment which means it is a backend side solution, there is no alternative way to run your script other than running it on a server (browser extension is considered client-side).

**In theory:***
However, you could use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to expose your puppeteer results to an API endpoint, where you could define which page you want to scrape with a GET `url` parameter (e.g. Google's homepage: https://my-server.com/my-puppeteer-endpoint?url=https://google.com). This could be called by your extension's click.

*Note:* this means `https://my-server.com` should be available 24/7 to serve your extension. As an example, this is how Grammarly or Google Translate browser extensions communicate with their official APIs.

Fragments of the advised solution:

```js
// puppeteer
const getPage = async (url) => {
...
  await page.goto(url)
...
  return resultsOfScraping
}
```

```js
// express
app.get('/my-puppeteer-endpoint', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.query.url
    const response = await getPage(url)
    res.json(response)
    console.log(`/my-puppeteer-endpoint?url=${url} endpoint has been called!`)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})
```

You can get more ideas from Thomas Dondorf's evergreen answer on client-side puppeteer usage: [How to make Puppeteer work with a ReactJS application on the client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031823/how-to-make-puppeteer-work-with-a-reactjs-application-on-the-client-side)

---

On the extension side, you need to make sure that you give permission to your server `https://my-server.com` to be called without CORS errors, see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107774/how-do-i-send-an-http-get-request-from-a-chrome-extension).

---

***EDIT/WARNING:** as on the server you will need the [`'--no-sandbox'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681161/why-puppeteer-needs-no-sandbox-to-launch-chrome-in-cloud-functions) puppeteer launch flag, in general, I advise instead to set up your own sandbox on a Linux server if you'd go this way (see in the link above).

Another possible way would be if you'd create a whitelisted domain list where you could allow pages you trust, others would be forbidden by the extension (required to be implemented on the server-side).

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful advice, just wondering if bundling the script in webpack would this work?

Comment: @user303749 I am afraid you can't use it in a sense of how puppeteer-web worked. you can take a look at this if it suits your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540795/how-to-bundle-puppeteer-for-production-deployment-using-webpack